# Como resolver o problema de medium trust em asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Estou desenvolvendo um site em Asp.Net MVC5.
Ao publicar o site na LocaWeb e tentar logar com meu usuário recebi a mensagem:

```
Attempt by security transparent method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.ClaimsIdentityFactory`2+<CreateAsync>d__0<TUser,TKey>.MoveNext()' to access security critical method 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity.AddClaim(System.Security.Claims.Claim)' failed.

Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is partially trusted, which causes the CLR to make it entirely security transparent regardless of any transparency annotations in the assembly itself.  In order to access security critical code, this assembly must be fully trusted.
```

Eu utilizo **Identity** e também alguns componentes da **DevExpress**.

Foi só então que entrei em contato com o suporte que me disse que o problema ocorre porque o servidor deles só roda em medium trust: http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Security_Level_de_servidores_Windows_em_ambiente_compartilhado

No site da microsoft diz que a solução é colocar dentro da tag `<System.web>` do meu `web.config` a tag `<trust level="medium" originUrl="" />`.

Ao fazer isso recebo o seguinte erro do servidor: `This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file.`

Ou seja, a locaweb bloqueou essa alteração atrabés de um arquivo de configuração global (pelo menos foi o que eu entendi do erro).
Já tentei colcoar a tag `<location allowOverride="false">` mas tambem não resolveu.

O suporte da locaweb só sabe dizer que o erro é de programação, mas não sei como resolver.
Alguém ai sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Bom conselho! Mas preciso resolver.

Comment: Nossa cara, como pode? Eu vi que eles tem um servidor win server 2003 que aceita full trust, será que consigo mudar o servidor? O que você acha?

Comment: Ok. Vou analisar apossibilidade. Ai, já da a dica pra onde foi tua hospedagem.

Comment: a KingHost roda ASP.Net em modo full trust #ficaadica

Comment: A KingHost roda Asp.Net em full trust, mas só em .Net 4.0. Falando com o suporte me garantiram que funcionaria, quando contratei que fui publicar surge o erro. Pedi pra migrarem para um servidor que suportasse .net 4.5 e full trust e me responderam que nao oferecem isso.

Comment: uma pena, as aplicações que eu rodei lá eram asp.net 4.0 mesmo (instancias do CMS Composite C1). Tente comentar as tags referente a configurações de impersonate e do proprio full trust no seu web.config, resolve uns erros lá fazendo isso

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema. Hospedei na KingHost e eles disseram que o ambiente Full Trust roda em ASP.NET 4.0 e preciso que o ambiente seja 4.5
Já resolveu o problema?

Comment: Tente mudar se `web.config` para `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
  <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>`

Comment: Já tive um problema parecido. Alguns Host não permitem mesmo.
Tente fazer um teste no Windows Azure: http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/ Meus últimos projetos tenho utilizado o Azure como host, agora eles tem servidores no Brasil também.

Comment: Alguma solução?

Comment: @DaniloOliveira A solução foi subir pro Azure mesmo. Os provedores como #LocaWeb tem implementado um nível de segurança de medium-trust para asp.net 4.0 e 4.5. E por nada no mundo estão dispostos a mudar.
A melhor solução é subir pro Azure. Você consegue hospedar inclusive de forma gratuita um site básico com um banco de até 20Mb.
Se for usar as mesmas configurações que uma #LocaWeb da vida o preço fica muito próximo. Então, compensa.